# odoo : look for method I click on button "add line" in tree view

Tags: odoo, treeview

I am looking for the method which is called when I click on button `add a line` in **odoo treeView** .Can you please help me .

Comment: Check the [add](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/17.0/addons/web/static/src/views/list/list_renderer.js#L245) function inside the list renderer